# Sharepoint dropdown filter

Tags: dropdown

I have two lists - list A with columns A,B and C (all types number).
Then list B - with columns number (type number), text (type text), category (type text) with following lines:
1, text 1, A
2, text 2, A
3, text 3, B
4, text 4, C

And I want following - if i add new line in list A, i want to make dropdown list - for column A with only text 1 and text 2 (and in column A will save number 1 or 2), for column B text 3, etc.

I managed to make dropdown list with all lines from list B, but I don't know, how to filter it.

I hope I wrote it clear and sry for my English ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term you are looking for is Cascaded Drop downs.. On selection of one drop down the other filters..

You can achieve them using [SPServices Cascading Drop down](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns) Javascript Library

Or you can use [InfoPath Forms (customize list forms in InfoPath) to achieve Cascaded Dropdowns](http://blog.salamandersoft.co.uk/index.php/2011/11/implement-cascading-drop-down-for-forms-in-sharepoint-2010/)

Comment: Ok, thanks. Unfortunately I do not have permission to the server to upload new library, so I try Infopath.

Comment: Okay, if that answers your question.. Please tick mark it to close the question.. (Of course after you have tried the solution)

Comment: I tried it... but I have problem with InfoPath, because on server is InfoPath service not running. But I managed to make it with filtered Data Source and it works :)

Comment: Great.. tick mark the answer please :)